# How can I push an repository that contains subrepositories to a new bare repository and pull it back on another computer?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I created a Git repository that contains some subrepositories. Now I want to push those repository with all subrepositories to a new bare repository on an external hard drive (called e).

After that, I want to pull the complete repository on an other computer from that hard drive.
However, I only get empty directories without the files from the subrepositories.

I've taken the following steps:

1. create three subrepositories:

   ```
   cd /d/all/sub1
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "initial commit"

   cd /d/all/sub2
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "initial commit"

   cd /d/all/sub3
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "initial commit"
   ```
2. create the repository that contains the 3 subrepositories:

   ```
   cd /d/all
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "initial commit"
   ```
3. create a new bare repository on the external drive

   ```
   cd /e
   mkdir all
   cd /e/all
   git init --bare
   ```
4. push the repository to the new bare repository

   ```
   cd /d/all
   git remote add origin /e/all
   git push --set-upstream origin master
   ```
5. pull all on an other computer from external harddisk

   ```
   cd /h/test
   git init
   git pull /e/all
   ```

How must I change the steps 4 and 5 to achive my goal?

Comment: Use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would have a remote repository for the submodule. E.g. lets say that there is a submodule on github. Then between 4 and 5 you would do

```
git submodule add https://github.com/Mellbourn/sub4.git
git commit -m "added submodule 4"
```

And after 5 you would do

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

After that you will have a submodule (populated with content) in the subdirectory `sub4` in the `test` repo.

One problem with your example is that your sub-repos have not really become proper submodules. You are creating them locally inside the repository. The point of submodules is that they are reproductions of repos *outside* your own repo.

Submodules are neither automatic nor intuitive. I highly recommend that you [read about them](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Is there no way for locally inside/nested repositories? I find out, that relative paths possible. So I try 'git submodule add ./sub1'. But I doesn't find out how to push that to the bare repository.

Comment: @tonirush once you have initialized the submodules correctly, they recide as nested directories inside the outer repository. So relative paths are then possible. 
That far you have thought correctly. Your problem is that you should initialize the subrepositories correctly, preferrably with a remote, before you try to nest them inside your outer repo.